# Converting .csv (.geo column in sf package) to shapefile in R

Tags: shapefile, r, convert, sf

I have extracted values from raster layers and now want to convert it to shapefile. The CSV file contains values of different bands and one column .geo in sf package. Any ideas to convert the CSV file to shapefile in R?

```
library(sf)
# Read data file
LS2013<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/Rice-Paper/master/LS_2013.csv",header = T)
```

The shapefile can be in geographic coordinate system (4326).

Comment: How did you create that CSV? Why does it have the locations in that format? Did you extract the values using R and the raster package? Have you used `write.csv` to save a spatial object when you could have used `st_write`? You should edit your question to show us the data format in the CSV so we don't have to download it.

Comment: I extracted values in GEE.

Answer (score 2):

What you have in that column are fragments of `geoJSON` for point coordinates. Install `geojsonsf` and then read and create an `sf` object:

```
> LS2013<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/Rice-Paper/master/LS_2013.csv",header = T)
> LSsf = st_as_sf(cbind.data.frame(LS2013,geojsonsf::geojson_sf(LS2013$.geo)))
> plot(LSsf)
>
```

You can then save the `sf` object to any other spatial format (please use GeoPackage if at all possible, shapefiles have problems and GeoPackages will mostly work when people say "send me a shapefile") using `st_write`.